# Define multiple custom objects in a single package file in Java

Tags: java

I have a main class, `Simulator` with a main function where I will run a simulation.  In the main function of `Simulator`, I want to be able to declare both `Atoms` and `Moves` where a `Move` object contains an `Atom` and a timestep.

To do this, I've set up the following package hierarchy:

```
//Simulator.java
import particle_simulator.*;

public class Simulator{
   public static void main(String args[]){
   ...
   }
}
```

and

```
//particle_simulator/Atom.java
package particle_simulator;

public class Atom{
   ...
   public Atom (){
   ...
   }

   class Move implements Comparable<Move>{
     public Atom atom;

     ...

      public Move (Atom atom, double time){
         ...
      }
}
```

When I try to declare `Atoms` in the main function of `Simulator` I get no error.  However, when I try to declare `Moves` in it, I get the following error:

```
$javac Simulator.java
Simulator.java:46: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Move
location: class Simulator
         move_queue.add(new Move(atoms.get(i),5));
```

Why can't `Simulator.java` create `Move` objects?

Comment: Because Move is an inner class of Atom. o to get to it you need `(new Atom()).new Move()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your inner class public and static if you want to construct it independent of your Atom:

```
public class Atom {

    public static class Move {

    }

}


public class Simulator {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new Atom.Move();

    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I got a warning: `$javac Simulator.java -Xlint
Simulator.java:46: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.PriorityQueue
         move_queue.add(new Atom.Move(atoms.get(i),5));
                       ^
1 warning`  Should I worry about that warning?

Comment: That warning is letting you know that PriorityQueue accepts a parametric type. 

`PriorityQueue<Atom.Move>  move_queue;'

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: Thanks.  I added the parametric type to the PriorityQueue and now I get no error or warning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide public access AND create it from an instance of Atom

```
package particle_simulator;

public class Atom{
  ...
   public Atom (){
    ...
   }

   public class Move implements Comparable<Move>{
       public Atom atom;

        ...

   public Move (Atom atom, double time){
     ...
  }
}

// In Simulator
    Atom a = new Atom();
    Atom.Move m = a.new Move(a, adouble);
```

Without too much knowledge of what you're doing, I don't think it really makes sense to have Move as an inner class of Atom.  Why not put it in its own file?

Comment: I agree. I want to create a package hierarchy where `Simulator` uses the `particle_simulator` package which contains both `Atom` and `Move` at the same level.  However, I don't know how to give `Move` access to `Atom` if they're at the same level.  Perhaps I could have `Simulator` use `particle_simulator` which contains `Move` and have `Move` use another package containing `Atom` but that seems strange.  Is it my best option?

Comment: "*I don't know how to give Move access to Atom if they're at the same level.*" If you understand how the Simulator can access Atom, how is it you don't know the answer to your question??